# Python: Selenium: find_elements_by_xpath max 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

So, I right now have a working piece of code that looks like this;

```
if browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'dealspg_item_cell')]"):
    snipes = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'dealspg_item_cell')]")
else:
    print "Cant find snipes.. Retrying..."
    browser.get("https://www.rolimons.com/deals")
    time.sleep(2)
    print "Reloaded browser... Retrying..."
    if browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'dealspg_item_cell')]"):
        snipes = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'dealspg_item_cell')]")
    else:
        print "Shutting down engine..."
        browser.quit()
        checking = False
        print "Restarting script..."
        break
```

This all works fine. And it gets 60 elements. Now I only need the first 10. How can I make it that it will only `find_elements_by_xpath` with a limit of 10?

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

==== EDIT ====

This code takes at the moment 4 seconds. And I hope to reduce this time by putting the max on 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use:

```
//[yourXpath]/*[position()<=10]
```

in Your case

```
//div[contains(@class, 'dealspg_item_cell')]/*[position()<=10]
```

Comment: Thanks! I couldnt find anything about this on google. So I just searched for it.

Answer (score 1):

Although using xpath is good answer. You can also refer css selector as per performance respective. Personally i faced such issue where xpath is not working but CSS selector is

```
div.dealspg_item_cell:nth-child(-1n+10)
```

**Explanation `nth-child(-1n+10)`**

`+10` indicates here the node position, from where we want to pick the elements
`-1n` all nodes before the 10th node

Lets say there are total 11 element then selection would be something like :

[image]

Another example would be `nth-child(1n+10)`, It means all other nodes after 10th node

[image]

You can explore more from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)